# Backup to Google Drive include account(s) information?

Tags: backup, restore, accounts

I have been experimenting with restoring [backups](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup) to a freshly factory-reset phone but I'm noticing that not a single account beyond the initial Google Account is being restored to freshly restored-from-backup phone.

This makes the whole concept of restoring quite limited.  Sure data is there but the user having to go re-create all of the needed accounts manually is a real pain.

Is there something I am not (as a user) understanding about the backup/restore facility?